# looping through to draw chessboard with python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a chess board using turtle graphics but i'm not sure how to loop through every other square to paint it black

```
for each_row in range(number_of_rows):
    for each_column in range(number_of_columns):
        if (each_column % 2) ==0:                #this is the line that's doubtful
            draw_black_box()
        else:
            draw_white_box()
        goto_next_box_pos()
    goto_next_row_pos()
```

the drawing of boxes work just fine but I feel like I looped through it wrong.

The existing function goto_next_box_pos() takes care of repositioning the turtle to where the next box in the row is to be drawn.  The existing function goto_next_row_pos() takes care of repositioning the turtle to where the next row is to be drawn.

Comment: This is a perfectly sensible way to structure your code.

Comment: okay but in line 3, should  I have put in>>  if (each_row % 2) ==0: instead ? or is it okay like this

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with this is it will only alternate colours for changing columns, not changing rows - so you'll end up with a stripy board, not a chequered board. You need to change your conditional to include the row number, so that both rows and columns alternate colours. It so happens that simply adding the numbers together will get you what you want:

```
if ((each_row + each_column) % 2) == 0:
```